# How to find the particular API gateway/lambda from the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The URL of the API endpoint reads something like this:

```
https://hasa12tb3.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/dashboardOps
```

The API is functional and works, but I can't find which API gateway/lambda it works from
. I have gone through the list of the API gateways in the us-west-2 region but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the API gateway configuration just enter the following link in your browser (which redirects you to your `dev` stage): https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-west-2#/apis/hasa12tb3/stages/dev